# How keep grenades equipped after throwing one?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I know a grenade route where I need to flash twice, fairly quickly. However, when I throw my first flash it automatically switches back to my primary gun.

Is there a setting or control to stop this from happening so I can flash twice in a row without having to switch weapons again?

Comment: I'm not sure but if i remember right there was no option available neither can I remember any console command to disable the auto swap. However you could bind your flash's directly e.g. `bind "x" "use weapon_flashbang"`

Comment: not to be rude.. but throwing a flash twice to the same spot is not a good practice

Comment: @Jenson it can be useful to throw 2 flashes in quick succession. On a dust2 B rush, a double flash is quite a good entry to the site, see this example: https://youtu.be/cVSu1-1UN54?t=606 I guess this is the kind of situation that the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

i am sorry for you, but this is not possible. All you can do is lower the time you need to swap to the grenade and throw it. I would recommend watching this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haWAKyn34iM) by AndreN and learn what hes teaching.

Comment: Hey there, I removed your signature, as everyone can see who you are.